# Sort the manualy created array of active records by created_at

Tags: arrays, sorting, ruby-on-rails-2

there I am working with rails 2. I am having manually created array having different values of active records, I want to sort the array by created_at, but not getting any clue, I am stuck. Please help

Here is my code:

```
@player_ranking_details[:qb].each do |nfd|
  @new_nfd << nfd.player.news_breakers.last
end
```

and output :

```
[#<NewsBreaker id: 4562, player_id: 981, title: "Newsfeed for week 6", source: "http://pyromaniac.com", active: true, publish_time: "2017-05-25 06:05:00", feature: false, sticky: false, created_at: "2017-05-25 06:06:38", updated_at: "2017-08-09 12:53:41">, #<NewsBreaker id: 3361, player_id: 187, , title: "Troy Polamalu ruled out for Week 15", source: "http://twitter.com/jimwexell/status/6701947444", active: true, publish_time: "2009-12-15 18:00:00", feature: true, sticky: false, created_at: "2009-12-15 20:33:46", updated_at: "2009-12-15 20:33:46">...]
```

Is there any way to sort my records in array ny created_at in desc order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can sort an array any time with attributes, here `@new_nfd.sort_by { |i| i.created_at }`

For descending order, `reverse` the above result.